# Get count based on two id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How can I get back a 'count' from my redeemed table based on both incentiveID and recipientID and add it to the following query.

```
SELECT recipient.*, incentive.*
            FROM recipient 
            INNER JOIN incentive ON recipient.incentiveID=incentive.incentiveID
            WHERE recipient.mobile = :mobile 
            AND recipient.incentiveID = :incentiveID"
```

The query below brings back recipient and incentive data. I would like to extend this and have a ‘count’ on how many times a recipient has redeem. i.e. redeemCount

Redeemed Table Looks like this and is linked by incentiveID ,recipientID

```
RedeemedID incentiveID recipientID timestamp
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a count of redemptions per employee by incentive, you can try something like

```
select a.recipientID,a.incentiveID,count(*)
  from redeemed a
 group by a.recipientID,a.incentiveID
```

If you want to add a count of *all* redemptions, you can't get it into your current query as you'd have to include elements of the incentive table to your GROUP BY clause. You can create a query to total redemptions per individual with something like this:

```
select a.receipientID, count(*)
  from redeemed a
 group by a.recipientID
```

You can then join that back to the recipient table to get things like a user name, or other relevant per-user information.

Hope that's helpful.